# Do we have an update of ShareKit for iOS 5 which supports automatic reference counting?

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest, ios5, sharekit, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to migrate my app which was initially developed in iOS 4.3 to iOS 5. All the third party code is being migrated with Xcode's refactor tool. But it doesn't convert the code and shows a lot of errors with the third party files like ShareKit and ASIHTTPRequest. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you convert just unstick the third-party files that are causing you problem. Because ARC is still reference counting you are able to mix ARC and non-ARC files in the same project.

Comment: thanks, i figured it out. i used a flag in the compiled files for all the third party implementation files.

Comment: Which is the procedure to unstick third-party files? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is the flag: -fno-objc-arc. You have to replace -fobjc-arc (which enables ARC) with -fno-objc-arc. Just search the documentation for the flag, there's a screenshot ...

Comment: I'm still getting a ton of warnings, are you getting a lot of warnings?